# Understanding Eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

We have a matrix $A$ of size $N \times M$, where $N\le  M$. Consider a vector $V$ of length $N$.

Now I take product of $AV$ to get a vector $W$ of length $M$. Here I have projected the original vector $V$ to $W$ to a higher dimensional space. Now if take outer product of $W$ to get a $M\times M$ matrix we get a rank one matrix.

Does the principal eigenvector has a geometric meaning?

This should be similar to $W$ but it has to get some properties of the row space of $V$ as well? Any comments? Sorry if the question is trivial and makes no sense.

Comment: I think you mean $VA$ otherwise dimensions don't match up.  It'll also be easier to read if you use capital letters for matrices and lower-case numbers for things like the dimension.

Comment: If you do all the computation, you'll have $(VA)^{T}(VA)=A^T V^T V A=\Vert V\Vert^{2} (A^T A)$.  So the eigenvectors all come from $A^{T}A$ which is a square symmetric matrix.

Comment: The eigenvector will have characteristic of V as well is not it?

Comment: The norm of $V$ will essentially scale the eigenvalues, but shouldn't have any effect on the eigenvectors.

Comment: This would mean that eigenvector is quite different then VA. I was doing some simulation which is not quite that.

Comment: There's no reason to believe that $VA$ would be an eigenvector.  The direction of the eigenvectors is independent of $V$.

Comment: Do you mean direction of VA is independent of eigenvector? I can understand that VA is not an eigenvector. But could not perceive as independent. May be but I cannot see it.

Comment: @Travis Consider A as a orthogonal basis like Fourier Transform. The Eigenvector of A transpose A is quite different then VA.

Comment: I mean VA transpose VA